# Struts jQuery CKEditor Always Output UBB rather than traditional HTML

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, ckeditor, struts2-jquery

My question is by using this CKEditor plugin: "http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/CkeditorEditor" in Java/JSP Struts2.

I always get the ubb code(like `[b][i]test[/i][/b]`), not html code (like `<b><i>test</i></b>`).

I've searched for resources on the web for several hours and still cannot find any solutions ... very few people use this plugin and very very little resource can be found...

My struts config and ckeditor work fine.

My code:

```
<sjr:ckeditor 
            id="richtextEditor" 
            name="richtextEditor" 
            rows="8" 
            cols="80" 
            width="800"
            uploads="false"
            loadingText="Loading..."
            toolbar="MyToolbar"
            skin="kama"
            dataType="html"
            customConfig="/xxx/js/ckeditor.config.js"
    />
```

Please help~~

Comment: If you are saving this data, what datatype did you use to store your rich-text data ?

Answer (score 0):

Two great rules for performing effective searches are:

- use proper names when searching: `UBB` is the [`Ultimate Bullettin Board` forum software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBB.classic), while the code itself it's called `BBCode`, [`Bullettin Board Code`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode). It would be hard to find something searching UBB instead of BBCode;
- when a plugin incorporates a third party software, always (first) search for the third party software itself, not for the plugin customization: you will find more informations searching `CKEditor` instead of `Struts2-jQuery-Richtext` plugin.

That said, both `CKEditor` and `Struts2-jQuery-Richtext` starts by default on `HTML` mode, you must explicitly ask for turning on `BBCode` mode on startup;

Try restarting with the default configuration, then add stuff once at time, trying it until it breaks. Then, bypass that parameter...

You can find the default configuration on the [**Showcase of Struts-jQuery**](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) (under Widgets -> Richtext):

```
<sjr:ckeditor 
                    id="richtextEditor" 
                    name="echo" 
                    rows="10" 
                    cols="80" 
                    width="730"
                    height="250"
                    uploads="true"
                    onFocusTopics="focusRichtext"
                    onBlurTopics="blurRichtext"
                    onChangeTopics="highlightRichtext"
                    value="Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos."
                />
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! At first, I didn't know how to call this type of format ([b]xxx[/b]) so I used UBB. I've used ckeditor before and implemented it in ASP 3.0, but Struts2-jQuery-Plugin is a brand-new plugin, even when I customized the "toolbar" attribute for "Full" and "Basic", it shows the same result.

Comment: That's the problem of Struts2 jquery. It doesn't work normally even in  Struts2 jQuery Plugin Showcase http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

Comment: It works for me :| I can click View Source and get HTML, not BBCode... can you explain *what* and *how* is not working for you in the showcase ?